# Coursera - Learn Angular - Why can't I get my app.js load?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have put in the HTML code per the instructions given to me this far.
But when I try loading the page it gives me nothing but:

The tabs:
The Menu
Appetizers
Mains
Desserts

The description:
 image: dish.name , dish.name , dish.label , dish.price | currency , dish.description

I thought it might be the version of angular I am running, but I just downloaded the latest one and it still doesn't work. I have tried moving the files to be in the same directory as the html file, same issue. I then tried to put the angular and app codes within the html document itself and still the same result. I even have deleted the cache thinking that that would be the issue, but still have the same view.

I know it is something stupid, but my brain is fried and I can't see the forest for the trees. All of the css loads just fine. It's just the app.js which is not loading. I am including the main.html followed by the app.js files below for any further hints. I am trying to move into the portion of the course where I learn Grunt (hence the build/endbuild comments.) So I would be greatly appreciative of some help.

```
<!-- MAIN.HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row row-content" ng-controller="menuController as menuCtrl">
<div class="col-xs-12">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:menuCtrl.isSelected(1)}">
<a ng-click="menuCtrl.select(1)" aria-controls="all menu" role="tab">The Menu</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:menuCtrl.isSelected(2)}">
<a ng-click="menuCtrl.select(2)" aria-controls="appetizers" role="tab">Appetizers</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:menuCtrl.isSelected(3)}">
<a ng-click="menuCtrl.select(3)" aria-controls="mains" role="tab">Mains</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:menuCtrl.isSelected(4)}">
<a ng-click="menuCtrl.select(4)" aria-controls="dessert" role="tab">Desserts</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<ul class="media-list tab-pane fade in active">
<li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in menuCtrl.dishes | filter:menuCtrl.filtText">
<div class="media-left media-middle">
<a href="#">
<img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src="{{dish.image}}" alt="{{ dish.name }}">
</a>
</div>
<div class="media-body">
<h2 class="media-heading">{{ dish.name }} <span class="label label-danger label-xs">{{ dish.label }}</span> <span class="badge">{{ dish.price | currency }}</span></h2>
<p>{{ dish.description }}</p>
</div>
</li> 
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
</body>

</html>

<!-- SCRIPTS/APP.JS -->
var app = angular.module('confusionApp', [])

.controller('menuController', function(){
this.tab = 1;
this.filtText = '';

var dishes=[
{
name: 'Uthapizza',
image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
category: 'mains',
label: 'Hot',
price:'4.99',
description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
comment: ''
},
{
name: 'Zucchipakoda',
image: 'images/Zucchipakoda.png',
category: 'appetizer',
label: '',
price:'1.99',
description: 'Deep-fried with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a tamarind sauce.',
comment: ''
},
{
name: 'Vadonut',
image: 'images/vadonut.png',
category: 'appetizer',
label: 'New',
price:'1.99',
description: 'A quintessential experience, is it a vada or is it a donut.',
comment: ''
},
{
name: 'ElaiCheese Cake',
image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
category: 'dessert',
label: '',
price:'2.99',
description: 'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake with Graham cracker crust spiced with Indian cardamoms',
comment: ''
}
];
this.dishes = dishes;

this.select = function(setTab){
this.tab = setTab;

if(setTab === 2)
this.filtText = "appetizer";
else if(setTab === 3)
this.filtText = "mains";
else if(setTab === 4)
this.filtText = "dessert";
else
this.filtText = "";
}

this.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
return (this.tab === checkTab);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out `ng-app` which is used to initialize angular in the page

Change

```
<html lang="en">
```

To

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">
```

Comment: D'oh! Thank you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what was already said. I was missing the ng-app variable. I must have lost this when I was transferring it from one file to the next. Thanks again.